# Super easy php link construct

Tags: php

```
$out_terms[$term->name] = '<a href="'custom-result/' .' $term_link . '">' . $text . '</a>';
```

Please help me check where the code gone wrong,any missing notes etc,as I am really 0 into php

Comment: What is the problem, first of all? Please edit your question to make it more understandable otherwise it will be considered as low quality as it's not going to be helpful for future users.

Comment: try this '<a href="custom-result/'

Comment: `.' $term_link .` needs to be `. $term_link .`

Answer (score 1):

```
$out_terms[$term->name] = sprintf('<a href="custom-result/%s">%s</a>', $term_link, $text);
```

Comment: `sprintf` is not always a good idea - I would rather use string concatenation.

Comment: @GiamPy can you elaborate or provide citation on why/when it isn't a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (**best construct**) :

```
$out_terms[$term->name] = "<a href=\"custom-result/$term_link\">$text</a>";
```

or :

```
$out_terms[$term->name] = '<a href="custom-result/'.$term_link.'">'.$text.'</a>';
```

Comment: The first one is not going to work, I highly suggest to use `{$var}` as the code looks cleaner.

Comment: @GiamPy Without { }, it works.

Comment: True, my bad, because it is not an array. However, it is a good practise always using {} to it looks cleaner and it creates a good habit.